# how to send email with embedded attachments - images (laravel imap)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, imap

I'm trying to send an email with laravel. With this function I can send emails and attachments.

But when I try to send images, providers like gmail tend not to accept all types, for example:

```
<img src = "base64">
```

What I'm trying to deploy is sending these images as an inline attachment, but to no avail, this is my code.

```
$email_status = Mail::send([], [], function($message) use ($to_name, $dest,$in_message,$name,$subj,$cc,$bcc,$files) {
    $message->to($dest, $to_name)
    ->subject($subj)->setBody($in_message,"text/html");
    if(!empty($cc)) $message->cc($cc);
    if(!empty($bcc)) $message->bcc($bcc);
    $message->from("email@gmail.com",$name);
    if(!empty($files)){
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $message->attach($file->getRealPath(), array(
                'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),       
                'mime' => $file->getMimeType())
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Okay, that works, but how to use [Inline Attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#inline-attachments)

In the body of the html I tried:

```
<img src="{{$message->embed($files[0]->getRealPath()) }}">
<img src="{{$message->embed($files[0]) }}">
```

I'm using files[0], because files is an object array of file type, sent by javascript.
[Object File](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File)

When this email arrives at its destination, and I inspect it, I have:

```
<img>
```

Comment: I don’t know if laravel will do it automatically, but inline images (in HTML) are usually done with Content-ID headers and a cid: URL.  You might need to construct these yourself.

Comment: @Max Inline Attachments -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#inline-attachments